# Why does my locally installed npm module work, but the same module installed from npmjs give a 'module not found' error in NextJS?

Tags: npm, next.js

I have a rather strange problem with the npm module I'm building.

This is my class in LocalisrClient.js

```
export class LocalisrClient {
    client;
    language = 'en';
    constructor(authorizationToken, projectToken) {
        this.client = new HttpClient(authorizationToken, projectToken);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

in index.js, I simply do

```
import { LocalisrClient } from './LocalisrClient';
export { LocalisrClient };
```

Now, the strange part. If I install the package from my local folder (`npm i <path to my package>`), when I run `next build` or `npm run build` everything works perfectly. But if I install the package from npmjs (`npm i localisr@dev`), when I run `next build` or `npm run build`, I got

```
unhandledRejection Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '<path to project>/node_modules/localisr/dist/mjs/LocalisrClient' imported from <path to project>/node_modules/localisr/dist/mjs/index.js
```

I also tested with a different react project (CRA) and a NodeJS app, and works perfectly. NextJS is the only one that has issues.

Any ideas / suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't related to Nextjs, you can reproduce this in node by running `import('localisr')`

Comment: I think the problem is a bad package publish. Your package is trying to do `import { LocalisrClient } from './LocalisrClient';` but I don't think node supports imports of files without extensions.

Comment: @AndyRay thank you for your reply. You are right, I added the extension and now it's working.